Integration of a Trained Model in Android Studio
How to accurately integrate a tflite model in android studio?
I am having difficulty in making this model work for my application, basically the model is trained to distinguish two different class of fish (tilapia and bangus). Here's initial code i created to make the model work. I tried checking on youtube but its a different thing so i cant get a hang on it. When the TestImage class (responsible for capturing image) has started the app just crashes/exits.
TestImage.java
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class TestImage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private TextureView textureView;
    private TextView textView;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession;
    private Size previewSize;
    private Interpreter tflite;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        textureView = findViewById(R.id.texture_view);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.result_text);
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(surfaceTextureListener);

        loadModel();
    }

    private void loadModel() {
        try {
            MappedByteBuffer modelFile = loadModelFile("best.tflite");
            tflite = new Interpreter(modelFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(String modelPath) throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getAssets().openFd(modelPath);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
    }

    private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener surfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(@NonNull SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(@NonNull SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(@NonNull SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(@NonNull SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            classifyFrame();
        }
    };

    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            previewSize = new Size(640, 480); // Set a default preview size
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
                return;
            }

            manager.openCamera(cameraId, new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
                    cameraDevice = camera;
                    startPreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
                    camera.close();
                    cameraDevice = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
                    camera.close();
                    cameraDevice = null;
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startPreview() {
        if (cameraDevice == null || !textureView.isAvailable() || previewSize == null) {
            return;
        }
        SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        if (texture == null) {
            return;
        }
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        try {
            CaptureRequest.Builder builder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            builder.addTarget(surface);

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    if (cameraDevice == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    cameraCaptureSession = session;
                    try {
                        cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(builder.build(), null, null);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void classifyFrame() {
        if (tflite == null || cameraDevice == null) {
            return;
        }
        TensorImage tensorImage = new TensorImage();
        tensorImage.load(textureView.getBitmap());

        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = tensorImage.getBuffer();
        inputBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        float[][] output = new float[1][2];
        tflite.run(inputBuffer, output);

        float bangusConfidence = output[0][0];
        float tilapiaConfidence = output[0][1];

        if (bangusConfidence > tilapiaConfidence) {
            textView.setText("Bangus");
        } else {
            textView.setText("Tilapia");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(surfaceTextureListener);
            } else {
                // Permission denied
                finish(); // Close the app
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

}


**
build.gradle(App)**
`plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        mlModelBinding = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:25.0.0")
    implementation("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.8.0")
    implementation("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.2.0")
    implementation("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")
}



AndroidManifest.xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity android:name=".CaptureImage" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SignInActivity"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".TestImage"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

